# wget read input from standard input

Tags: wget, stdin

From the wget man page

[§ 2.4 Logging and Input File Options](http://gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options)

```
‘-i file’
‘--input-file=file’
     Read urls from a local or external file. If ‘-’ is specified as file, urls
     are read from the standard input. (Use ‘./-’ to read from a file literally
     named ‘-’.)

     If this function is used, no urls need be present on the command line. If
     there are urls both on the command line and in an input file, those on the
     command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved. If ‘--force-html’ is
     not specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.
```

I tried doing

```
wget -i - www.google.com
```

It downloaded a file `index.html`, but then it hangs. Even after I pressed
"Enter" several times, it still hangs. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have not closed your 'file' `wget` continues waiting for you to type more into stdin. To terminate, press ctrl + d [EOF terminator]

Comment: Pressing ctrl+d would give you `No URLs found in -.
FINISHED --2012-11-20 23:15:43--
Downloaded: 1 files, 12K in 0.001s (14.9 MB/s)` message

Comment: This is useful for things like `grep google urlList.txt | wget -i -` (i.e. download every page in the file which has "google" in it). If you want to just pass in URLs on the command line, you can do `wget url1 url2`.