# Download with wget and grep combined

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I want to download a website with `wget`, then I want to extract a specific link from the website with the command `grep` and then I want to download this "grepped" link again with `wget`.

My attempt:

```
wget -O website https://www.testwebsite.com/dir/site |
grep -E 'https://testwebsite.com/downloads/picture1' | wget -O myPicture
```

The problem is, that it is downloading the testwebsite.com/dir/site but doesn't extract the link and download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `-i -` [parametars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478857/wget-read-input-from-standard-input) on the last wget to read the links from stdin. Also the first wget should output to stdout with `-O -`

E.g.

```
wget -O - https://testwebsite.com | grep abcd | wget -i - -O outfile
```

Comment: If https://testwebsite.com is a html page, you may want to parse it as html: `... | wget --force-html -i - -O outfile`

Answer (score 1):

wget has a recursion facility. You can invoke it with `-r`:

`wget -r 'https://testwebsite.com'`

(This works for links included in html)

The recursion depth can be set with `-l`, see `man wget`.